# Get some inputs and store in one variable without list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two simple functions: `test1` gets some inputs (student name) and function `test2` prints each name.

In fact I wanted to practice `*args` and `**kwarg`. I know by making list but is it possible directly?

And for getting two serried of input and make dictionary like students name and students mark I have same question.

I found `input().split()`. But it didn’t work for pressing enter after each input.

```
Def test1(*args):
  While True:
      Args=input(“enter st name: “).split(‘\n’)
      if args==“stop”:
          break
   Return args
Def test2(*args):
     for i in args:
         print(i)
test2(*test1())
```

Comment: Your code has syntax problems -- you capitalized `def` and `while`, you used curly quotes instead of straight quotes. Did you post this on a mobile device?

Comment: You need to use a list. Each time through the loop, you need to append the input to the list.

Comment: `input()` only reads one line at a time, so it doesn't make sense to use the newline delimiter in `split()`.

Comment: thanks for editing. you are right I posted on mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible using `yield`:

```
def test1():
    while (args := input("enter st name: ")) != 'stop':
        yield args

def test2(*args):
    print(*args, sep='\n')

test2(*test1())
```

Comment: If you're trying to make it short, `test1` could just `return iter(lambda: input("enter st name: "), 'stop')`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure there's a way to do what you're asking. It sounds like you want to mix 2 approaches that can't be mixed (to the best of my knowledge, but I might be wrong). In any case, my answer might show you a different way of accomplishing part of what you're looking for.

It sounds like you're talking about some sort of generator function that makes use if `yield`, like so:

```py
def test1():
    while True:
        text = input('Write something:')
        if text == 'stop':
            return
        yield text
        
def test2(func):
    for text in func():
        print(text)
    
test2(test1)
```

Comment: They said they want to practice `*args`. Can you use `test2(*test1())` with a generator?

Comment: @Barmar Hah, my turn to be corrected! I think they need to decide whether they want to use `*args` or to have it be printed directly (i.e. without having to store it somewhere before passing multiple values at once to a function). I'll leave my answer here just in case it helps someone with a similar (but not exactly the same) issue.

Comment: Or you could just edit it so it does do `test2(*test1())`...

Comment: @KellyBundy Not sure where you're referring this change to be made, is it on the method call at the last line of my code snippet? If so, that doesn't work, the text from the input won't get printed.

Comment: It does get printed if you also undo your changes to `test2`.

Comment: I mean, you can literally take your `test1` and their rest (only have to fix `Def` to `def`). @Barmar's question looks like a trick question, as the answer is "Yes".

Comment: @KellyBundy I don't know which interpreter/python version you're using, but with Python 3.11.4 what you're suggesting doesn't work. It only prints the inputs once you input "stop" to end the execution, instead of immediately after the input.

Comment: Well, yes, but it does print, and they didn't ask for immediately, did they?

Comment: I think that's the intended result. You enter all the names, then it prints all the names.

Comment: @KellyBundy They also didn't say **when** they wanted it to be printed, so either of us could be right. In any case, there's no point in continuing this discussion any further until the OP clarifies what they want. I hope my answer helps someone nonetheless.

Comment: They said *"I know by making list"*, which wouldn't print immediately, either, and they only complain about the list.

Comment: @KellyBundy Sure, whatever makes you happy, I'm not here to win arguments, just to share knowledge :)

Answer (score 0):

*Capitalization Errors:*

1. Change **Def** to **def** for function definitions.
2. Change **While** to **while** for the loop condition.
3. Change **Return** to **return** for returning values from functions.

*Syntax and Logic Errors:*

4. The condition in the `while` loop should be `while True`, **not** `While True`.
5. Args should be assigned the result of `input("enter st name: ")`, not the split result. You don't need `.split('\n')` here.
6. You should compare `args` (the function argument) to "stop," not `Args` (the variable).
7. Instead of comparing `args` to "stop," you should check if the entered student name is "stop" to exit the loop.

```
    def test1():
        student_names = []
        while True:
            st_name = input("Enter student name (or 'stop' to quit): ")
            if st_name == "stop":
                break
            student_names.append(st_name)
        return student_names

    def test2(*args):
        for name in args:
            print(name)

    test2(*test1())
```

Comment: thanks. but you used of list in your code. I'd rather not to do it. infa